# Why won't qemu-system-x86_64 accept multiple threads or sockets for virt-install?

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a server that I am running the Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server on and I'm trying to start up a Virtual Machine but I'm having some trouble. I can only get it to use one CPU at a time (running it through the roof) even if I specify multiple cores. If I try to specify multiple threading or sockets, it won't even start and gives me a cpu topology error. I have 16 cores with 2 threads each so that's not an issue. I'm running a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5550 @ 2.67GHz with HTT enabled so I don't understand the problem. If I specify vcpus=2,cores=2 it only uses one, if I try to use vcpus=2,cores=2,threads=2 it doesn't even start and just gives me the error.

Here is the command I am using:

```
sudo virt-install --name SMB-Ubuntu-Server --ram=1000 --vcpus=2,threads=2,cores=2  --cpuset=1,2 --cpu host --hvm --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/SMB-Ubuntu-Server-vm1,size=150 --cdrom /var/lib/libvirt/boot/ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso --graphics vnc
```

I don't want to use to many cpus because this is one of the more simpler vm's that I want to use on this machine.

Comment: Show us your actual entire virt-install command. If it is an existing VM, did you try to use `virsh edit` and try to change the number of vcpus from whatever is set in the .xml definition file? I always allocate 4 cpus, and have never had any troubles.

Comment: @DougSmythies I updated the question to include the command. It shouldn't be an existing one as whenever it failed, I would destroy and undefine it. And, where is the .xml definition file saved for a machine?

Comment: Try changing this: `--vcpus=2,threads=2,cores=2  --cpuset=1,2` to this `--vcpus=3` (for example). The .xml files are at `/etc/libvirt/qemu/` , but never edit directly, only via `virsh edit`. For example `virsh edit SMB-Ubuntu-Server`.